How can i make a flashlight in Ursina?
I didn't find any questions on this already, not even AI was able to help me. So any of you got any idea?
i have this code at the moment, for the player i am using the FirstPersonController:
flashlight = SpotLight(parent=player.camera_pivot, position=(0, 0, 0), direction=(0, 0, -1))
flashlight.color = color.white
flashlight.intensity = 10
flashlight.spot_angle = 30

It kind of does follow the player, but it doesn't light up the floor and it doesn't light up any entity right, they are just constantly lit up. They should only partly light up if you look at them.
